# Is it normal to notice underneath the plastic barrier in crawlspace drops of water?

Tags: vapor-barrier, moisture, crawlspace, radon

A radon barrier was placed using 6mil polyethylene sheets and sealed with silicon in at the seams. However, I do notice in certain spots a couple of drops of water underneath the sheet.

- Is this okay? Will there be a mold damage or something and can it penetrate the barrier?
- Shouldn't the moisture disappear over time?

In general I want to know if I should be worried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is absolutely normal. What you do not want to see is standing water under it. I have seen moisture under my plastic all the times I visited my crawlspace, mold has never been a problem. The idea is though to have no organic material like wood, grass, anything else that would decay, trapped under the plastic.